# USD (dollar) cost of Transaction

Tags: gas

I've a Ropsten testnet transaction that cost : 0.00254868076441 ETH, the corresponding USD cost is 5.24 US$ ? If i deploy the contract in mainnet is the same cost?

Comment: Thanks for the correct english syntax in the question, i´m not a US native,

Answer (score 0):

You need two dimensions to calculate the cost of a transaction:

- Total gas used (eg: 21000)
- Gas price (eg: 50gwei)

You can have a fair degree of certainty that the same transaction will have similar "Total gas used" on mainnet — considering the transaction will perform the similar computation on each side.

But "gas price" is generally more costly on mainnet, so check websites like https://ethgasstation.info to get to the current gas price, and use the calculator to get to the information you need.

```
21000 gas ✖️ 50,000,000 wei
= 0.00105 ETH
```

Considering ETH value at $2000, would give you:

```
0.00105 ETH * $2000
= $2.10 cost of transaction
```

https://ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php

Comment: Thank you very much! i´m new in Ethereum.